# PLN similitud entre textos cortos

Tags: python, nlp

Soy nuevo en el mundo de data science y estoy haciendo un proyecto para un empresa de venta de comida preparada del que tengo el histórico de los 2 últimos años pero cada plato está escrito de diferentes formas lo que hace que a la hora de analizar, los resultados serán erróneos.

Una vez obtenidos los unique() del histórico, estos son el tipo de diferencias que deberían de figurar como el mismo plato:

- "quesadilla de jamón york y nachos con queso y guacamole"
- "quesadilla de jamón york y queso con nachos y guacamole"
- "quesadilla de jamón york, y nachos con queso y guacamole"

---

- 'Albóndigas con espaguetis'
- 'Albóndigas con Espaguetti'
- 'Espagueti con albóndigas'
- 'Espaguetis con albóndigas'
- 'Espaguettis con salsa de tomate y albóndigas'

---

- "arroz a la cubana"
- "arroz a la cubana (1 huevo frito/ración)"
- "arroz a la cubana (plato maestro)"

No obstante, hay platos que aunque sean muy similares se deben conservar como diferentes. En el siguiente ejemplo, solamente "crema de puerro" y "crema de puerros" serían el mismo plato, mientras que con el resto se desea conservar dicha diferencia:

- "crema de puerro y patata"
- "crema de puerro"
- "crema de puerros"
- "crema de puerro y calabacín"
- "crema de puerro y calabacín con quesito"
- "crema de puerro y calabaza"

---

He utilizado el paquete fuzzybuzzy, con el que he podido iterar cada uno de los unique() con el resto, devolviendome ratios de similitud (fuzz.ratio y fuzz.partial_ratio). Un ejemplo de las entradas que más parecidas a "crema de puerro":

- crema de puerro || 100 || 100
- crema de puerro y calabacín || 100 || 71
- crema de puerro y calabacín con quesito || 100 || 56
- crema de puerro y calabaza || 100 || 73
- crema de puerro y patata || 100 || 77
- crema de puerros || 100 || 97
- gourmet - bocadillo de crema de queso || 83 || 46
- sandwich de pavo y crema de queso || 83 || 50
- tomates rellenos de atún y crema de queso || 83 || 43

He leído también sobre la distancia de Levenshtein, pero no sabría cómo aplicarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo que se me ocurre es probar por eliminar las stopwords(signos, pronombres, artículos, preposiciones, etc.) de cada platillo, (entre mas stopwords consideres podria ser mas optimo pero no siempre, ten cuidado con esa parte) y ordenarlos por palabra, de esta manera siento que se solucionaría en gran medida el problema.

Para el primero ejemplo quedaría así

```
stopwords = [" de ", " o ", " y ", " con ", " la ", " su ", " en "]
signos = [",",".","!"]

platillos = [
    "quesadilla de jamón york y nachos con queso y guacamole",
    "quesadilla de jamón york y queso con nachos y guacamole",
    "quesadilla de jamón york, y nachos con queso y guacamole"
]

for i in range(len(platillos)):
    platillos[i] = platillos[i].lower()
    for word in stopwords:
        platillos[i] = platillos[i].replace(word," ")

    for sig in signos:
        platillos[i] = platillos[i].replace(sig,"")

    platillo_lista = sorted(platillos[i].split(" "))
    platillos[i] = " ".join(platillo_lista)
    print(platillos[i])
```

La salida obtenida seria la siguiente:

```
guacamole jamón nachos quesadilla queso york
guacamole jamón nachos quesadilla queso york
guacamole jamón nachos quesadilla queso york
```

Tambien puedes aplicarle a toda la cadena un `lower()` que convierte todo en minúsculas o un `upper()` para mayúsculas y así evitar que te las procese como cadenas diferentes.

Ahora para los casos donde se están escribiendo diferentes las palabras como por ejemplo `Espagueti` y `Espaguettis` podrías usar un lematizador, el cual toma la raiz (lema) de una palabra dada, es decir para palabras como `programa`, `programador`, `programando` el lema podría ser `program`

Hay un paquete en python llamado `nltk`, que contiene herramientas para el lenguaje natural y hace este proceso mas sencillo el cual te pude servir para esos casos.

Te pongo unos ejemplos de palabras lematizadas con este paquete.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("spanish")

palabras = ["correr", "corriendo", "corre", "programar", "programando","programa"]
lema =  [stemmer.stem(palabra) for palabra in palabras]
print(lema)
```

Y esta es la salida del codigo:

```
['corr', 'corr', 'corr', 'program', 'program', 'program']
```

Aun así con palabras mas complejas puede que no funcione, de cualquier manera te dejo una liga donde puedes encontrar información así como la pagina oficial del paquete, donde hay muchas herramientas y podrás encontrar mas métodos o los parámetros adecuados para tu problema.

[Pagina oficial](https://www.nltk.org/) 
[Información de lematizador en su pagina oficial](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#module-nltk.stem) 
[Tutorial completo en ingles](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/stemming-lemmatization-python)

Espero te pueda servir de algo.
Saludos